# Is it possible to have submodules in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

There are several web services that support multiple android applications written in Laravel. Each web service contains multiple modules. The board of directors decided to move all of the web services into one Laravel installation as modules. So the `webServer1` which is an independent web service will have to be a module of the collection of web services integrated in to one Laravel installation.

Because some web services are big enough to have modules and they are implemented by `nwidart` package, I have to implement it as what it is in this new integration. So the only way to implement it is to be able to have submodules.

I would like to know does `nwidart`  support such thing? and how can I do this?

Besides that, is it in general, a good idea to to such thing? May be I can dissuade  the he board of directors :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using composer like for example

```
"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/",
    "SubModule\\": "SubModule/Path"
}
```

Then create a service provider
inside your module like

```
<?php

namespace Your\Directory\Here;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class CustomServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $defer = true;

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application events.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__ . '/resources/views', 'YOuCanNameHereAnyThing');
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->mergeConfigFrom(__DIR__ . '/config/config.php', 'config');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need *any* third party package to make a Laravel application modular, and I'd argue that doing so introduces an unnecessary dependency. Composer allows you to autoload any folder you want under a particular namespace via PSR4 autoloading.

Sometimes it may also make sense to put some code in different packages and pull them in when required using Composer. It's possible to use any VCS repository as a source for a package, so your modules can be in a private repository if necessary.

Making your code more modular in general is a good idea because it allows for code reuse. For instance, if you built some functionality that would be useful on other projects, you can place it in a package by itself and require it with Composer.